# Is there a wat to style just the user input text in a <input type ="text"> not the input field itself?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I am using Cordova to make an android app and I have a text field where the user types into. Im using a keyboard function so I can listen for the done key on a text field. When the event fires I want to be able to "animate" the text that was just entered into the field. I don't necessarily want to animate it, but really just put a circular box around the text so that its clear the input has been accepted.

For example:

This is what it looks like after they've typed their text and before they've pressed done on the keyboard.

[Text input before submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i4DH.png)

When the event fires I want to style the text as such where the font weight changes and the background of the text gets bubbled. Is this  possible?

[Text input after submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hON1p.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the function that you're using to listen for the done key, you can use `Element.classList.add()` to add a class to the `<input type="text">` element.

```
const inputElement = document.getElementById('your-input-element')
inputElement.classList.add('recipent-submitted')
```

Then apply whatever styling you want to `.recipent-submitted` in your CSS file.